# How to stop a Kafka Connector running in daemon mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently start a kafka Connector in `--daemon` mode below:

```bash
bin/connect-standalone.sh -daemon \
/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties \
/kafka/config/custom-connector.properties
```

How do I stop this connector process gracefully?

I am currenlty using `top` command to locate a java process and use `kill -15 pid` to stop it. I found this quite not practical because I cannot specify the connector by some properties to stop it.

Is there any way to stop a `kafka connector` in a way like executing a command below? Or any better alternatives?

```bash
kafka/bin/kafka-connect-stop.sh \
/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @OneCricketeer's answer.

I wrap my command using systemd script below.

Create a `kafka-connector.servce` file in `/etc/systemd/system` as below

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Kafka Connector

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties /kafka/config/my-connector.properties"
```

Start the kafka connector using

```bash
sudo systemctl start kafka-connector
```

Stop the kafka connector using

```bash
sudo systemctl stop kafka-connector
```

Check the status of the kafka connector using

```bash
sudo systemctl status kafka-connector
```

Comment: Ideally, you use `connect-distribued.sh` to preserve the Connector status in Kafka, rather than on disk

Answer (score 1):

To stop a connector, and not the worker, use `PUT /connectors/{connector}/pause` REST API endpoint.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest

Otherwise, yes, to stop the worker, you can use `kill`, or you can wrap it in SystemD script, and use `systemctl stop` to do the same.

Comment: You can also use Connect in a docker container or Kubernetes pod, and run stop actions through those

Comment: Thanks for the `SystemD script` advice. I also leave my answer as a reference.